# HowTo read actual C# *.cs source code files into objects that can be queried

Tags: c#

I need to write a windows app that reads an actual C# .cs file and then tries to identify what procedures on that source file do NOT have a parameter named "int userID" (it's kind of a Code Checker).

Is there something out there that already reads C# files into some sort of objects that have a property named "procedureName" and another property named "parameterList" ...that can be queried ??

If not, what would be the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Check this out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn

Comment: Interesting ...I bet there must be some code out there for what i need using this. thanks

Comment: If you can work with compiled code (DLL/exe) it can be achieved with reflection out of the box...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Do you have by any chance a url link to a reflection sample to get the list of procedures in a file ?

Comment: [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) have a sample of all information you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using NRefactory which should be able to provide the solution.
The following is an example which will find all the Methods in a file with the Name of bob.

```
CSharpParser parser = new CSharpParser();
SyntaxTree syntaxTree = parser.Parse(@"namespace Test
    {

        public class TestClass
        {
            public void Method(string bob)
            {
            }
        }
    }");

var result = syntaxTree.Descendants.OfType<MethodDeclaration>().Where(x => x.Descendants.OfType<ParameterDeclaration>().Any(y => y.NameToken.Name == "bob"));

if (result.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("We Win");
}
```